# Sending requests to webpages using Python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I need to send "M6" value to this `http://wap2.mobi/votes/?id=16552` webpage using python.
I have some problem to do that because the website submit the vlaue using javascripts.

This is the html source for the input:

```
<div id="info">
<input type="text" id="company" name="com" size="20">
<input type="button" value="Send Now" onClick="getData();"></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

and the `js` code is:

```
    function getData()
        {
        var Send = document.getElementById("company").value;
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "../votes/comments.php?id=97775547",
           data: "com="+Send,

           beforeSend: function() {
               $("div#info").html("<img src='../loading.gif'>loding...");
           },
       success: function(result)
       {

           $("div#info").html(result);
    }

     });
        }
```

Please if someone can help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused as to your question... Why are you trying to post values to that page rather than posting it straight to the url listed in the js?

Comment: So you are expecting the python equivalent code snippet for this javascript function to make the `POST` request ?

Comment: I think (though I'm not sure) that the OP is trying to make a Python program to automate calling the "votes" url he lists. Hmmm.

Comment: hmmmm i need to post value to this webpage http://wap2.mobi/votes/?id=16552 using python @TanveerAlam

Comment: @romeo Please review my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)** module for making this `POST request` in python.

```
import requests

url = "http://wap2.mobi/votes/"
payload = {'id': '16552'}
r = requests.post(url, params=payload)
print "url : ", r.url
print "response status code : ", r.status_code
```

So in **response** we get status 200. ([***200 means - The request has succeeded***](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html))

```
url : http://wap2.mobi/votes/?id=16552
response status code : 200
```

Comment: @romeo If the answer was correct or helpful please raise and accept and if not then please let me know so that I can modify according to your expectation.